# Record login delay in a company in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, authentication, delay

I am currently working on MVC project. Project is about Time management. In my project, I want that when the employee of a company login by or more than 15 mins delay then the delay mins should recorded in the database as the login time of company is 10:00 am. When the employee wants to see his last month login detail then he should get the delay time of particular date. This will help the admin to deduct the salary accordingly without searching the whole data of the employee.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: you should focus the question a bit. It's too open.

Comment: Are you currently recording the login time of employees in the DB?

Comment: yes I am recording the login time..

Comment: Then the approach I would go for in your place is generating a report based on a DB query.